# file_get_contents("php://input") returns empty when the code is placed in a sub-folder

Tags: php, facebook-messenger-bot, facebook-webhooks

I am experinmenting with Facebook Messenger Bot.

When the below webhook (`index.php`) is placed under `/var/www/wei48221.com/html/`, it could capture
the data sent from Facebook and save them in "fb.txt" under `/var/www/wei48221.com/html/callback/`.
However, if the webhook (`index.php`) is placed under `/var/www/wei48221.com/html/callback/` it cannot
capture the data sent from Facebook even though the new callback URL `https://wei48221.com/callback`
has passed Facebook's verification.

Below is the content of "index.php".

```
<?php
file_put_contents("/var/www/wei48221.com/html/callback/fb.txt", file_get_contents("php://input"));
```

Could anyone shed some light on this issue?

Comment: Are there any errors in the PHP log?

Comment: The location of the script shouldn't make any difference in whether it can read from `php://input`

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Will check the PHP log..

Comment: Found out where the problem is. Both "URL/callback" and "URL/callback/" will pass Facebook's URL verification. However, only the "URL/callback/" will give the expected result. Thank you for letting me know the location of the script shouldn't make any difference in whether it can read from php://input.

Comment: `URL/callback` results in a redirect to `URL/callback/`. But redirects are processed with GET not POST, so they don't post the data through the redirect.

Comment: You should give FB the full URL, `URL/callback/index.php` so no redirects are involved.

Comment: Ahh. I didn't know URL/callback results in a redirect to URL/callback/.. Thank you so much :-)